# MDX Calculated Member on Fact Dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube, multidimensional-cube

I have written below query to get count of job numbers from a fact dimension. It is working fine.

```
WITH SET V_Lots AS
{[ABC Lots].[ABC Type].&[A]
,[ABC Lots].[ABC Type].&[O]}
*
{[ABC Lots].[ABC Load Nbr].[ABC Load Nbr]}
MEMBER 
   [MEASURES].[ABC_V_CNTRS] 
AS  
   COUNT(V_Lots)
SELECT
   {[MEASURES].[ABC_V_CNTRS]} ON COLUMNS
FROM 
    [ABC Model]
```

Now I have to save this in the cube, I tried to rewrite it as a calculated member but its returning null value. Please let me know if I am missing something here?

```
(COUNT([ABC Lots].[ABC Load Nbr].[ABC Load Nbr]),{[ABC Lots].[ABC Type].&[A]
,[ABC Lots].[ABC Type].&[O]})
```